# Develop a TV application with flutter, how to achieve scrolling effect

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I want to implement a layout that can be scrolled like ListView, GridView, etc. in a TV application. Since the TV is controlled by the remote control, I don't know how to get it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Check out and play around with [RawKeyboardListener class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RawKeyboardListener-class.html) to listen to hardware (like remote) key presses. Using the Up, Down, Left or Right keys (if available), you can select the relevant item using the index count. I guess you can make your app's canvas to move offset a row or column when you highlight the second-from-last item, to reveal other list items that would be currently off-canvas.